# Print items from list, without quotes

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def load_map( filename):
    map_output = []
    map_open = open('map.txt','r')
    for line in map_open:
        line=line.replace("\n", "" )
        line=line.strip().split(" ")
        map = map_output.append(line)
    map_open.close()
    return map_output

print(load_map('map.txt'))
```

This is my script's output:

```
[['3', '8', '4', '0'], ['1', '-1', '-1', '10'], ['2', '-1', '-1', '11'], ['7', '6', '5', '9']]
```

I want to print those numbers **without quotes**:

```
[[3, 8, 4, 0], [1, -1, -1, 10], [2, -1, -1, 11], [7, 6, 5, 9]]
```

Comment: You mean without quotes around the numbers?

Comment: another way you may see this kind of thing done with python is `_map = [int(val) for val in line.strip().split(" ")]`

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Just map them to integers. Instead of this:

```
line=line.strip().split(" ")
```

do this:

```
line = list(map(int, line.strip().split(" ")))
```

Also, don't redefine the `map` built-in by the return value of `list.append()` in the body of your loop, else this code won't work.